# Receiving True boolean value for Django unit tests instead of False

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm doing some unit tests for my Django database and I keep getting a `True` value instead of the `False` I expected to get because that entry isn't in my database:

```
import requests
from django.test import TestCase
from convoapp.models import InputInfo

class InputInfoTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #valid entry
        InputInfo.objects.create(name="Skywalker", conversation_id='1', message_body='I am a Jedi, like my father before me')
        #invalid entry - missing 'name' field
        InputInfo.objects.create(conversation_id='4', message_body="No, I am your Father")
        #invalid entry - integer entered instead of string
        InputInfo.objects.create(name='Leia', conversation_id=3, message_body='You are a little short')

    def test_for_valid_entries(self):
        luke = InputInfo.objects.get(name='Skywalker')

        self.assertTrue(bool(luke), True)

    def test_for_invalid_entries(self):
        vader = InputInfo.objects.get(conversation_id='4')
        #invalid because of non-strong entry for conversation_id
        #leia = InputInfo.objects.get(name='Leia')

        self.assertFalse(bool(vader))
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\documents\github\challenge\convoapp\tests.py", line 25, in test_for_invalid_entries
    self.assertFalse(bool(vader))
AssertionError: True is not false
```

Why is `vader`returning True? I assume it's because of `InputInfo.objects.create(conversation_id='4', message_body="No, I am your Father")`, is it because the entry is temporarily created? Because after the test ends it's not in my database

Comment: Can you explain why you think you should get a False here? If the entry wasn't in your database, `.get()` would raise a DoesNotExist exception; it didn't, so the entry *is* there.

Comment: Yes and yes. Tests have their separate database, and unless you are "maintaining" it explicitly, it gets created and destroyed each time you run your tests.

Answer (score 4):

the setUp functions is called before each test so yeah you have the `vader` entry in your db (because you request `conversation_id=4` which exists since `setUp` was called before testing).

That said, casting to bool doesn't make a lot of sense, if your trying to see if you have the entry or not you should user :

```
self.assertIsNone(vader)
```

or

```
self.assertTrue(vader is None)
```

This way you know exactly what you are testing

Comment: Okay I thought so, okay so I want to send a POST request to my server and test to see if the entry is added (it shouldn't). I'm using Python requests to send info to the server, but it's just sending to the test server right? So would I need to then import my function from my non-test code? if that makes sense lol

Comment: If your goal is to build unit tests you can't afford to send POST requests in the automated tests. What you should do is testing individually your views with different sets of parameters to see if your view reacts the way it should. For that the best way is to use Mock to simulate parameters / objects. You can find the doc here : http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html

Comment: Thank you I'll look that up.

Comment: Quick question though: why can't I afford to send POST requests? It's a very small project I'm doing right now, I tried sending a POST request in my `setup()` method but it doesn't seem to be POSTing info

Comment: Your webserver isn't running when tests are executed (or at least it shouldn't be), because tests should be executed in a brand new environment you control (otherwise you won't know for sure there is an issue in your code), so it can't accept POST requests. The philosophy of unit testing is to test very small chunks of code and you can't have a 100% control over a POST request (what if you don't have internet for instance ?)

Comment: Just to clarify this is on my locahost, so even if I ran the local server and executed the tests in another environment it wouldn't be alright? I appreciate you knowledge and help, but like I said this is for a small local project

Comment: Well, you can if you want - it will work - but that's not what unit tests are for.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating an object with the id 4 thus its returning true, and as its test database thus you cannot find data after the test ends

rather if you think its mistaking

try the lower code and check

```
def test_for_invalid_entries(self):
        vader = InputInfo.objects.get(conversation_id=5)
        #invalid because of non-strong entry for conversation_id
        #leia = InputInfo.objects.get(name='Leia')

        self.assertFalse(bool(vader))
```

Comment: Okay I thought so, okay so I want to send a POST request to my server and test to see if the entry is added (it shouldn't). I'm using Python requests to send info to the server, but it's just sending to the test server right? So would I need to then import my function from my non-test code? if that makes sense lol